# Magento: Having layered navigation on a special view

Tags: php, attributes, magento, e-commerce

I have a product attribute, `artist`, on each product. My client wants me to have a page for each artist that displays that artist's products. They want it to look exactly like the category views (layered navigation, etc). Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution that I've found to this situation is to use the excellent Yoast [Landing Pages](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/1915/yoast-landing-pages) module augmented with the Layered Navigation functionality from this sonassi [blog post](http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-knowledge-base/yoast-landing-pages-module-with-layered-navigation/).  That way, you don't have to create categories for each artist (sorry @Joseph, I've tried that approach and it's painful) but you get the advantages of Layered Nav.

You then create a static block with the artist description, photo, external links etc which will appear at the head of each listing page.

Actually it looks like Yoast's latest version now includes the sonassi code already, even better!

Comment: With a large catalog, I agree that it would be painful. Some boutique websites would spend more time doing it the other ways than just to create a few categories :) Thanks for relating the firsthand experience though!

Comment: @Joseph, absolutely, it all depends on the numbers - of attribute values, of available admin time, of $$ budget!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You may use Shop by Brand extension from Aitoc. But you need add layered navigation to the brand page.

Answer (score 1):

The hack way to accomplish this is to have an actual category page for each artist and include the relevant products as such. This may fall out of sync, but doesn't require much effort on your part.

Another option would be to use the artist attribute as a filter on a product collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter("artist", $someValue);
```

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: the product attribute approach is basically what the Yoast module does, except with a whole lot of nice features added in, especially for SEO and content management. I don't recommend that category approach.  The Mage category editor struggles with very large numbers of categories... the tree editor isn't designed for it.